# nodejs error when installing canvas-prebuilt on arm

Tags: node.js, canvas, npm, resemblejs

i'm trying to install resemble with "npm i resemblejs" but appears

```
node-pre-gyp ERR! install error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: 404 status code downloading tarball             
https://github.com/chearon/node-canvas-prebuilt/releases/download/v1.6.5-prerelease.1/canvas-prebuilt-v1.6.5- 
prerelease.1-node-v57-linux-arm.tar.gz
```

resemblejs have a dependence of "canvas-prebuilt" but i go to the webpage and don't exists (404), either exist a prebuilt in arm.

```
npm --v #is: 6.3.0
node --version #is: v8.11.3
```

Any suggestion for the installation? (Thanks)